# Dynamically deserialize json to types in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, jil

I am trying to make a generic handler in WEB API where I will get a JSON payload, and dynamically deserialize it to objects.
The thing is, that my method doesn't know yet what type the object it. So for that, there is a field inside the object, that says its own type.

What I want to do is to get that JSON, and automatically and dynamically deserialize all the object based on the types inside.

How can I achieve that? if at all...

Tnx

Comment: Load json `JObject.Parse`, then use `jObj.ToObject` according to your rules.

Comment: Take a String object as input (this will hold JSON), test it and parse it as needed.